# r - arrange values in a dataframe, within a group, based on a variable, in ascending or descending order

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Got stuck with what I think is a very simple solve, but somehow I cannot find a way.

I'm trying to `dplyr::arrange` values in a `dataframe`. The thing is I want to apply the function on groups using `dplyr::group_by`, and decide whether it is in ascending or descending order based on a variable inside.

A simple example:

```
library(dplyr)

test <- 
    data.frame(
        var1 = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
        var2 = c(1,3,2,5,9,7,8,3,5,9),
        var3 = c(rep("i", 5), rep("d", 5))
    )
```

Here I try to arrange by a grouping variable `var1`, but everything is in ascending order:

```
test %>% 
    group_by(var1) %>% 
    arrange(var2, .by_group = T)
```

The goal is to automate arranging based on `var3` values. More specifically, by ascending order if the `var3` is "i" and in descending order if it is "d", but within the groups.

Desired result:

```
data.frame(
    var1 = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5)),
    var2 = c(1,2,3,5,9,9,8,7,5,3),
    var3 = c(rep("i", 5), rep("d", 5)))
```

Comment: Try using ‘test1 %>% group_by(var1) %>% arrange(desc(var2))’ for descending order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you're looking for. You can add other cases to the `case_when` statement as well if there are more scenarios for `var3` that you need to tackle. Also, for default sorting, you can add something like `TRUE ~ var2` for the last case to handle an unknown value in `var3`.

```
test %>% 
  group_by(var1) %>% 
  arrange(case_when(var3 == "i" ~ var2,
                    var3 == "d" ~ -var2), .by_group = T)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   var1 [2]
    var1  var2 var3 
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
 1     1     1 i    
 2     1     2 i    
 3     1     3 i    
 4     1     5 i    
 5     1     9 i    
 6     2     9 d    
 7     2     8 d    
 8     2     7 d    
 9     2     5 d    
10     2     3 d
```

Comment: perfect answer. Will accept when available. Many thanks